# Multiple SSL certificates on single server

Tags: apache, ssl, lamp, multiple-domains

I have two domains pointed at one server(IP),

Site A - www.taus.net
Site B - www.tauslabs.com

Site A already has a wildcard SSL installed on the server. Now i need to install a multiple SSL domain for site B.

Can i go ahead and install an extra SSL certificate on a server which already has a wildcard SSL installed for a different domain? Will this affect anything on the server ?

Vinod

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/325897/48784 and http://serverfault.com/q/109800/48784 (both on Server Fault).

Comment: oh no, Forgot to check Server Fault. Thanks for the heads up, i will keep that it mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newer technology called SNI allows SSL for different domains to coexist on the same ip address.  Older browsers will choke.  If that's not a concern, you're in the clear.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04